# Magento 2: Get store information in frontend files

Tags: module, template, custom-template

I'm completely new (like 3 days in) to Magento Development so I apologise in advance if i'm asking a silly question!

I've really struggled to find a good magento course online so now i'm at the stage of trying to figure it out myself (which is probably a bad idea, but if someone can point me in the direction of a great course, i'm all ears)

I'm currently trying to access my store information inside a custom template file

`myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/templates/top_header.phtml`

and i'm including it inside my `default.xml` file like this

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
    <container name="custom.header.top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="name-number">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.header.top.content" template="Magento_Theme::top_header.phtml" before="-" />
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

I have had a look at guides online such as

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-store-information-magento-2.html

The bits of courses I have done haven't even mentioned the `code` directory yet. How can I implement something like this to access my store information in my `frontend` folder?

If someone could explain to me how it works, i'll be forever in your debt!

Comment: have you run all the deployment commands??

Comment: @Sumit i'm not sure, please can you explain